# how to get boolean isTouching or touch iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make an iPhone game that is set up such that the basic game logic is just a timer firing off every .02

The only control for the game will be to touch the screen (or not touch the screen) so I was wondering if there were any simple ways to quickly get a boolean value for whether or not the screen was currently being touched or not.

I am trying to avoid having to put in a bunch of logic to `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` to see whether or not someone currently has their finger pressed down.

Comment: If you use `NSTimer` you should note that the resolution of the time interval for a timer is limited to about 50-100 milliseconds, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to keep a `NSMutableSet` of the touches that are ongoing, add the touches to the set on `touchesBegan` and remove the touches from the set when you get the `touchesEnded` or `touchesCancelled:withEvent:` callbacks. To check if there is a touch ongoing, you check if there are any touches in the set.

Comment: This is sort of the only way to keep a record of touches still on the screen that I have found because touchesBegan and touchesEnded are very asymmetric.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a button on the screen and have different IBActions for touchUpInside and touchDown

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating everything every 0.2 seconds, and you don't want to "put a bunch of logic" in `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded`, why don't you create a `BOOL` called `isUserTouching`.  Set `isUserTouching = YES` or `NO` in the `touchesBegan` and `touchesEnded` methods respectively.

Simply placing a button over the game content could cause some weird behavior, however.

Comment: If the user puts one finger then another on the view, then removes one you get a touchEnded and set isUserTouching = NO when there is still a touch left